# R2HTML cannot open connection

Tags: r

I am producing a repetitive HTML report displaying tables and graphs computed with R. I am using functions from the R2HTML package, embedded in a for loop. I do not have admin rights on my machine.
At some point in the computations, I sometimes get the following error :

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>    cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>    cannot open file 'P:/My Documents/R/test.html': Permission denied

This does not happen at every run, nor at the same point in the code. 
I can get the same error when I try to run the following simple code :

```
require( R2HTML)

.HTML.file = file.path( 'P:/My Documents/R' , 'test.html' )  
# To set the access path to the HTML file  that will be created

cat(paste("<html><head><title>", 'test.html', "</title></head>", sep = ""), file = .HTML.file , append = FALSE ) 
# To create and initiate the HTML file

for( i in 1:100 )
{
    HTML('Test')
}
# To write the same line to the HTML file repeteadly
```

Most of the time this loop can run without any problems, but sometimes it will produce the above error (sometimes at the beginning of the loop, sometimes at the end).
Does anybody know what causes this? I am using R-2.15.0 on a Windows xp pro machine. If anybody can help me with this, I would be most greatful.
Thanks.

Comment: I've had this before. It happens because you are trying to write (append) to the file while the operating system still hasn't completed the previous operation. To fix this, possibly your best option is to append the data to an object in memory, then write to the file only when the loop is complete.

Comment: I see... However I am using some specific functions from the R2HTML package ( HTML.data.frame, HTMLplot ) to append data frames, graphs and text to the HTML file in a specific order. If I was only writing text, I think I could append it to a variable in memory and use only one call to the HTML function to export it, but here I'm not sure I can do something like that. If the problem comes from appending the file too fast, do you know if there is a way to tell R to slow down at some specific points in the computations? Thank you very much for your answer anyway.

Comment: You are writing to a HTML file, which is just text. So clearly appending to a character vector is precisely the same thing. Simply capture the output of `HTML()` and combine it with your previous results using `c()`. Then at the end of the loop, dump it to file.  This really works - I've done it.

Comment: Ok, this seems like a nice way to do it. From what I've seen, the `HTML` function appends the connection specified in `.HTML.file` and always returns `NULL`. Sorry to ask such a basic question, but how can I can capture the output of the function instead of having it appended to the connection. I couldn't figure this out from the `HTML()` help page. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Type `[r] capture output` into google and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked pretty well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Andrie in the comments, the solution is to capture the output of the R2HTML functions in string objects and use only one call to the HTML function to create the HTML file after the loop.